# How to share *argv[] in other .c files

Tags: c

I've got

- main.c
- something.h
- something.c

How can I use 
`char* argv[]`
in `something.c` file without having to call a function from something.c with `argv[]` as parameter?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to do that? What's wrong with passing values via a parameter list?

Comment: @mike, even though the argv itself is probably not a good thing to make global, its interpretation may be. Imagine a program with a lot of options and configurations from command line. It's probably too much of a hassle, and too many parameter passings if you keep passing the "struct config" object around instead of making it global.

Comment: @Mike because If I have e.g. 3 functions in something.c, and from main.c I'll be calling only one, and the other two will be called from the one called in main.c. Those 2 functions will need arguments. So at the end I will have to call all functions with arguments as parameters and the arguments will be only used in 2 of them.

Comment: There's no problems in parsing all arguments in one function called from `main` and set global flags (or flags in global structure) for example like [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/btaimagemodel/code/ci/tip/tree/src/cmdlnopts.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I recommend this in general, but:

**main.c**:

```
char **global_argv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    global_argv = argv;
    ...
}
```

---

**something.c**:

```
extern char **global_argv;
```

Comment: In something.c I have to include main.c ?

Comment: No no, they are separate files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables, but that isn't really clean code. There is nothing problematic with passing argv as parameter. However, you should do sanity checks in your main to control the data you get from the command line.

Comment: Yea, but if I have e.g. 3 functions in `something.c` and I'll be calling only one from `main.c` and the other 2 will be called from the function in `something.c`, then it won't look clean neither.